# responsive design css button over background-image, fixed position issues while resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am writing a responsive webpage that has a background image and a button over it. The button needs to be at a specific position on the image.  Now I am creating a div with the background-image (different for mobile, tablet and desktop breakpoints) and I create a css button on the image. The problem comes when I resize the window, within the same breakpoint, the background-image resizes but the css button is placed w.r.t the parent container of the background div and thus moves.

The code snippet looks like

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <a href="/gotohere.html">
        <span class="goto_btn">Click here</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

the css code for mobile breakpoint looks like

```
.imgContainer {
    background-image: url("mobile.jpg");
    height: 18em;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}


.goto_btn {
    bottom: 3.5em;
    font-size: 15px;
    right: 4em;
    background-color: #1867C3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 75%;
    padding: 10px 58px;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Now I can create such css rules for tablets and desktop similarly and it looks fine but the issue comes within the same breakpoint, lets say mobile, for different screen-size say iphone 5 and galaxy S4 screen, the position of goto_btn is not fixed although its placed position:absoulte; w.r.t the imgContainer which is position:relative;

Can I somehow position the goto_btn fixed with the imagConatainer div so that any resizing within the breakpoint keeps the relative position of button fixed with respect to the background-image ?

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is there a standard size for your images?

Answer (score 0):

i based the your buttons position according to your `.imgContainer` `width` and `height` tag

```
.imgContainer {
    background-image: url("mobile.jpg");
    height: 18em;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    clear: both;
}


.goto_btn {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #1867C3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 58px;
    position: absolute;
    top:16em;
    right:2em;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I have played with top and right as well as bottom and right a lot. Looks like it fixes the position for a viewport, say iPhone5 (4" screen) but lets say I try to resize it a little more accommodating for Galaxy S4 (5" screen"), the background-image scales, since its width is 100% but the position of button now changes and misaligns

Answer (score 0):

was able to get it working, to most parts by

(a) changing `background-size: 100% 100%` in imgContainer and

(b) proving `bottom`, `left` and `right` in % values in goto_btn

This did streteced the background-image in some edge cases (like galaxy note 3) but for most parts, it worked fine. Depends on the size of the image(jpg) for each breakpoint.

Comment: it worked for me on large screens but anything smaller than 1200 gets horribly stretched. any fix?